# ZenMate-like tool for Microsoft Edge or Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, privacy, microsoft-edge

I used to surf with Google Chrome and ZenMate plug-in was helpful at times. Now I want to use Microsoft Edge but have no idea what tool can replace the ZenMate plugin.

Please advise how I can temporarily change my IP / location when using Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a tool that is an "add-on" for Microsoft Edge but what you could do is use a VPN service to do the same thing. One I would recommend is [Private Tunnel](https://www.privatetunnel.com/home/). Not only will it change the IP of your browser but it will also change the IP of all applications on your computer when you run Private Tunnel.

> ## Private Tunnel
>
> Private Tunnel is a new approach to true Internet security creating a
>   Virtual Private Tunnel (VPT) or Virtual Private Network(VPN) that
>   encrypts, privatizes, and protects your Internet traffic.

Edit (@Bobrovsky wants a free VPN service)

If your looking for a free VPN service, I would check out [CyberGhost](http://www.cyberghostvpn.com/en_us).

> ## CyberGghostVPN
>
> Free, simple & secure access to content from all over the world
>   5 Million people have enjoyed our service so far!
>
> [image: CyberGhost UI]

Comment: Thank you. It works. It's a pity it's not completely free as ZenMate.

Comment: How about CyberGhost?

Comment: No problem, happy to help:)